# Android call blocking from web

Tags: javascript, php, android, callblocking

I made a service to monitor all the incoming and outgoing calls of android device on my website but now I want to block the calls from specific number from the same webpage.

Is their is anyway to do call blocking on android device by php or javascript code?

Comment: Some service providers have call blocking features. Some don't. When they do have call blocking capability, they are in control over how it works. For example, with Verizon, you have to go to a block page where you can enter up to 5 numbers to be blocked. (However, I tried it. I blocked my office phone. I called myself. It wasn't blocked.)

Comment: But android device can block the calls no matter which network or service provider you have.

Answer (score 0):

In the telephony broadcast receive, check if the number is one of the blocked number? If condition is satisfied then use following code to end it:

```
telephonyService.endCall();
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice......but for this my app will check on server for the list of blocked numbers ......can i block the number instantly as i click a button from website?

Comment: Then you will need code to synch the web database (the one being updated by button on your website) to your cellphone database.